# How to get event.relatedTarget closest class text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the below code. Why am I unable to get closest paragraph `.para` text of each of buttons using `$(event.relatedTarget)`?

As you can see I am getting dummy index number for each event related buttons as well:

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) ;
   console.log(button.index());
   console.log(button.parent().closest('.para').text());
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<div class="container"><p class="para">Winter</p></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  First Launcegr
</button>
<div class="container"><p class="para">Summer</p></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Second Launcegr
</button>
<div class="container"><p class="para">Fall</p></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Third Launcegr
</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's traversing the wrong part of the DOM. Try this:

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  console.log(button.prev().find('.para').text());
});
```